# Perform Roslyn conditional compilation with custom symbol (eg: "DEBUG") defined

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, conditional-compilation

I'm compiling a project using Roslyn with code resembling:

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var project = await workspace.OpenProjectAsync("SomeProject.csproj");
var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
```

I need to set a compilation symbol (such as `DEBUG` or `TRACE`, but in my case something altogether custom). How can I do this with the API?

I saw that `project` has a `CompilationOptions` property, but I didn't see anything relevant there.

---

EDIT Thanks to @JoshVarty who pointed towards adding code like this prior to compilation:

```
project = project
    .WithParseOptions(((CSharpParseOptions)project.ParseOptions)
    .WithPreprocessorSymbols("SOME_SYMBOL"));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Project.WithParseOptions()`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs,7d035001e42d5e0b) and [`WithPreprocessorSymbols()`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/CSharpParseOptions.cs,f87788ec2f6a72a9)

Comment: Thanks very much Josh, both for this answer and your fantastic series of blog posts on Roslyn.